# Application's icon not displayed in Mac OS10.9 (Mavericks )

Tags: qt4, osx-mavericks

I have qt application which icon located in my Desktop and in info.plist write that path. Something like this:

```
 <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
 <string>/Users/test/Desktop/icon.icns</string>
```

It works perfect in Mac os x 10.8.5. But after upgrading to 10.9 it does not work anymore.
When I put icon on app package and write in info.plist such

```
 <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
 <string>icon.icns</string>
```

it works again. Someone know why this happen?

QT version: 4.8.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way: I created soft link of icon (where it should be located) and put it on a package. During dmg installation I put a real icon instead of the link.

I do not know how, but it works. :))))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're seeing the issue here, but for Qt on OS X, you can define the icon in the Qt .pro project file and it works for both OSX 10.8 and 10.9.

So you can add this to your .pro

```
ICON = /Users/test/Desktop/icon.icns
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but in that case the icon will be includes in bundle under "Contents/Resources" folder. 
I can link to an icon and not include it in package on Mac OS X 10.8.5 by writing complete path in Info.plist file. I want to know can I do similar in Mac os 10.9 or it out of support. I do not find any documentation about that and its not work on it.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're asking, though I don't know for sure, I wouldn't be suprised to see it no longer work. The bundle is supposed to contain everything required for the application and from what I've seen in Apple's WWDC video talks it seems they're pushing more towards ensuring that.